# Having trouble converting tensorflow model to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I have used ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco_2019_01_03.tar.gz to train a simple model to detect car and bike but im not able to figure out how to convert it to tflite. i have used export_tflite_ssd_graph.py to create .pb file i have attached the tflite_graph.pb and tflite_graph.pbtxt file here. plese help me out thanks in advance

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17tGCG2H7NEB7StTPHTBcNuZzJWOjEAtm?usp=sharing

Comment: I will try. Do you have frozen graph or saved model? Can you share it again. The current link is not working.